# Problem with input position in std::fstream

Tags: c++, stl, std, fstream

Using `std::fstream`, after calling the `testFile.getline()` function, I call `testFile.seekg(1, std::ios_base::cur);` which its job is to advance the input position by 1, as it will do in every other scenario, but this time it simply does nothing and does not advance the input position. As shown in the code below:

```cpp
std::fstream testFile;
testFile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
if (testFile.is_open())
{
    testFile.flush();
    testFile.seekp(0);
    char msg[]{ "GETTING IT TO WORK;\nNEXT LINE;\n" };
    testFile.write(msg, 32);
    testFile.put('\0');
    testFile.flush();
         
    std::string header;
    header.reserve(100);
    testFile.seekg(0);
    testFile.getline(&header[0], 100, ';');
    header.clear();

    //testFile.seekg(1, std::ios_base::cur); 
    //uncommenting this code will do nothing only if getline has not been called 
    //immediately before it, will do the advancing
    testFile.getline(&header[0], 100, ';');
}
```

Calling `testFile.seekg(2, std::ios_base::cur)` will advance the input position by 1 in this scenario only, but 2 when there's no `getline()` call before it.

I have read the documentation and test every scenario myself, but this behavior is not explained anywhere in docs, nor is it an expected behavior by the programmer.

Using MSVC v143 and ISO C++20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The salient facts appear to be:

- advancing it by one seems to make no difference;
- advancing it by two looks like it advances it by one; and
- this is immediately following a `getline()` and it's doesn't cause a problem otherwise.

That seems to indicate you may have a `CR/LF` file where the actual line endings are `\r\n` rather than `\n`. I'd check the content of the file with a hex dump utility to see if this is the case.

It's possible seek is actually working on binary content rather than text content so that skipping one character only skips the `\r`. If that is the case, then you can probably fix it by reading a character into a junk buffer rather than trying to seek ahead one byte. The former should hopefully handle line endings correctly. In other words, change:

```cpp
testFile.seekg(1, std::ios_base::cur);
```

into:

```cpp
int junk = testFile.get();
```

And, in fact, that appears to be what's happening. Consider the following program which does roughly the same as your code, but seeks to each position in turn and reads the line, printing the first character it read:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream testFile;
    testFile.open("test.txt",
        std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
    if (testFile.is_open())
    {
        char msg[] = "a\nb\nc;";
        testFile.write(msg, sizeof(msg));
        testFile.flush();

        char buff[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
            testFile.seekg(i);
            testFile.getline(buff, 100, ';');
            std::cout << "<" << int(buff[0]) << " "
                      << ((buff[0] >= ' ') ? buff[0] : '.')
                      << "> <"
                      << int(buff[1]) << " "
                      << ((buff[1] >= ' ') ? buff[1] : '.')
                      << ">\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The output of that is:

```
<97 a> <10 .>
<10 .> <98 b>   *1
<10 .> <98 b>   *2
<98 b> <10 .>
<10 .> <99 c>   *1
<10 .> <99 c>   *2
<99 c> <0 .>
```

You can see that, when you seek to either the `\r` or the `\n`, the result of a character read is `\n` (decimal; 10 is line feed). I've marked the lines where that happens with `*1` and `*2`.

So it appears the underlying I/O routines for text files will do something like the following:

- if the next two characters are `\r\n`, you'll get a `\n` (`*1`).
- if the next character is `\n`, you'll get a `\n` (`*2`).

That's why it appears to not seek ahead by one when the next character is the `\r`. It *is* seeking but the behaviour is as described above (seeking to the `\n` then acting as per `*2`).

---

A good debugging option, by the way, would have been to output `testFile.tellg()` after each file operation just to see where it thinks it is.

Interestingly, when I do that (under Linux), the buffer appears to move okay but the string prints as empty. If I replace `string header` with `char header[200]` (and make other adjustments to match), it seems okay. Note that the seek ahead by one works here, probably because it's a newline-ending platform.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::fstream testFile;
    testFile.open("test.txt", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc);
    if (testFile.is_open()) {
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " a\n";

        testFile.flush();
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " b\n";

        testFile.seekp(0);
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " c\n";

        char msg[]{ "GETTING IT TO WORK;\nNEXT LINE;\n" };

        testFile.write(msg, 32);
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " d\n";

        testFile.put('\0');
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " e\n";

        testFile.flush();
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " f\n";

        char header[200];
        testFile.seekg(0);
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " g\n";

        testFile.getline(&header[0], 100, ';');
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " h\n";

        cout << '<' << header << ">\n";

        testFile.seekg(1, std::ios_base::cur);
        testFile.getline(&header[0], 100, ';');
        cout << testFile.tellg() << " i\n";

        cout << '<' << header << ">\n";
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
0 a
0 b
0 c
32 d
33 e
33 f
0 g
19 h
<GETTING IT TO WORK>
30 i
<NEXT LINE>
```

I'd suggest trying that code on your platform to see what it outputs.

---

The reason why the direct writing to string didn't work appears to be that `reserve()` does not necessarily make things ready for that. I had to actually *populate* the string to be at least big enough (size, not just reserve capacity) so the direct write worked. And of course, I had to adjust the length afterwards because it's quite valid for C++ strings to hold `\0` characters.

That's probably because the direct write simply places data into the string area but does *not* affect any other important properties of the string object (such as the length).

Refactoring the line reader out to this:

```cpp
void getUpTo(fstream &strm, string &str, size_t sz, char delim) {
    if (str.length() < sz + 1)
        str.resize(sz + 1);
    strm.getline(&str[0], sz, delim);
    str.resize(str.find('\0'));
}
```

and changing the calls:

```cpp
// from: testFile.getline(&header[0], 100, ';');
// to:
getUpTo(testFile, header, 100, ';');
```

made it work.

That's not immediately applicable to your line ending issue but you should keep it in mind if you appear to get empty/bad strings even when you fix that.

Comment: its a text format ansi encoded in notepad++ setting, and as with the CR+LF you're right it notepad++ says CR+LF, but what should I do?

Comment: @Leon: "you can probably fix it by reading a character into a junk buffer rather than trying to seek ahead one byte" :-) Having said that, I'm not sure this is the problem, since you're using `;` as the delimiter, not the default newline.

Comment: yes it has come to my mind as well to just advance by 2, but the reason why it does that really makes wonder, is there some sort of other text file format that the line ending is simply '\n'?

Comment: you were right using semi column as delimiter is actually affecting this or I guess any other thing will do too

Comment: the last two line is `"\nNEXT LINE"`  by advancing the position by one I expect to lose the new line character but that doesn't work

Comment: @Leon, as stated, it's probably because you're skipping only the `\r` in the `\r\n` line ending. See the answer text about reading a junk character rather than seeking (I'll expand on that a bit now).

Comment: I appreciate the code you wrote, could have made it easier like: `linestr.append(linestr.c_str());` after the `getline` and the reseaon why I used reserve over size was to use the `.size()` to instead of `strlen()` ofc after the append op otherwise string is empty, it only has c string

Comment: @Leon you are writing a string with `\n` in it to an `fstream` operating in *text* mode, so on Windows it will write `\r\n` to the actual file.  And when reading and seeking, it will treat `\r\n` as a single character `\n`.  If you don't want this behavior, put the `fstream` into *binary* mode instead, then it will treat each byte individually.

Comment: @Remy, based on the description, it appears seeking up by one when you're on the `\r\n` is *not* treating it as a single character. I would actually expect it to given the file is in text mode.

Comment: @paxdiablo makes sense, since seeking doesn't read bytes (it would be really inefficient if it did)